# Two <div> elements with nested <div> and <p> elements on same row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I show `test1, test2` on the same row?
I tried with `float: left;` and `display: inline;`, without any success.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-sm-12" id="oblgrad-text-class">
  <div class="form-group">
    <p name="oblgrad-text" id="oblgrad-text">test1, </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12" id="obshtina-text-class">
  <div class="form-group">
    <p name="obshtina-text" id="obshtina-text">test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `class="col-sm-12"` to `class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"`

Comment: Add `display: inline-block` to both of your `<div>` elements. But since you're using Bootstrap, changing `col-sm-12` to `col-sm-6` is the better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `col-sm-6` instead of `col-sm-12` and check

Comment: And wrap both `div`s with `<div class="row"></div>`